# mvn clean install command in terminal not working

Tags: java

I can't compile my code with terminal mvn clean install. There is error: The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.

Comment: Did you configure maven correctly with IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 1):

did you try to check in your environment variable?

1. check that you installed maven
2. add the maven path to the path variable under [System Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw6GB.png)